# Hadoop Type Conversion

Tags: java, hadoop, types

I have the following signatures for my mapper and reducer classes:

```
MapperPrime extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text>
ReducerPrime extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, LongWritable>
```

When I run the code, I get the following exception when execution reaches the reducer:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at ReducerPrime.reduce(ReducerPrime.java:1)
```

When I change the first generic type in ReducerPrime from Text to LongWritable, i.e.

```
ReducerPrime extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>
```

The exception is no longer thrown. What gives? Why/Where would java be seeing a LongWritable?

Doesn't the input Key,Value type in the Reducer exactly match the ouput Key,Value type in the Mapper?

Comment: Are you using `TextInputFormat`? If yes, your mapper's signature is incorrect.

Comment: Pls show your complete classes and stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why/Where would java be seeing a LongWritable

For the Mapper, the key for the `TextInputFormat` is the file offset, which is a long. The Value is the line of text, so a `Text` writable object.

> Doesn't the input Key,Value type in the Reducer exactly match the ouput Key,Value type in the Mapper?

Yes, it should, though since we can't see the code at the moment, hard to say what you've written as output.

Comment: That helped, and turns out I was missing the `job.set....Class()` commands before I started the job, which yes would have been seen if I pasted all my code.